# Displaying code using code highlighter

Tags: php, html, css

I want to insert some programming code along with the descriptions like a tutorial site.

This is the sample code for HTML code:

```
 $code = "
 <p>This is introduction to HTML </p>

  [code]
<html> 
<head>
    <title>This is sample descriptions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method='post' action='index.php'>
        <input type='text' name='username' value=''>
        <input type='password' name='password' value=''>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>

 [/code]
   <p> This is sample for PHP </p>
  [code]
  <?php
      echo "Hi, This is PHP";
  ?
  [/code]
  ";

   $code = mysql_real_escape_string($code);
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO tutorials SET tutorial='$code'");
```

To display I am retrieving the content from a database and using `htmlspecialchars` like,

```
   echo htmlspecialchars($code);
```

For highlighting the codes, I am using `google-code-prettify`, that requires that the code be in between `pre` tag with `prettyprint` class,

```
    <pre class='prettyprint'>
    echo htmlspecialchars($code);
</pre>
```

Where ever the tags, `[code]` and `[/code]` are replaced with  `<pre class='prettyprint'>";` and `</pre>` like,

```
 $code = str_replace("[code]", "<pre class='prettyprint'>", $code);
 $code = str_replace("[/code]", "</pre>", $code);
```

When I echo,

```
echo htmlspecialchars($code);
```

only plain text is displayed like:

```
 <html> <head> <title>This is sample descriptions</title> </head> <body> <form      method='post' action='index.php'> <input type='text' name='username' value=''> <input type='password' name='password' value=''> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> </form> </body> </html> </pre> <h5> 2. This is sample code for paragraph </h5> <pre class='prettyprint'> <html> <head> <title>This is sample
```

Comment: @YaMo The code is not prettified, instead, i am seeing plain text like, <html> <head> <title>This is sample descriptions</title> </head> <body> <form      method='post' action='index.php'> <input type='text' name='username' value=''> <input type='password' name='password' value=''> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'> </form> </body> </html> </pre> <h5> 2. This is sample code for para

Comment: shouldn't you terminate your pre tag before terminating your [code]?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `htmlspecialchars` **after** doing the replacements so the `<pre>` tags are escaped as well (and won't be rendered as HTML). Reversing the order should do the trick:

```
$code = htmlspecialchars($code);
$code = str_replace("[code]", "<pre class='prettyprint'>", $code);
$code = str_replace("[/code]", "</pre>", $code);
echo $code;
```

Further, have a look at [highlight_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) for highlighting source code.

Answer (score 0):

There are `<pre class='prettyprint'>` and `</pre>` statements in your code too. This may make the code not work as expected.

You may try by changing `<` and `>` in your code to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.